# Read from telnet socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

I would like to retrieve modem list from the CMTS, and I wrote a telnet client in C, that is executing this.
The problem is that sometimes I do not get all the data from the CMTS.
(If I reduce the 'delay' waiting time, the more I do not get all the data.)

```
char buf[50000];
int nbytes, sock;
struct sockaddr_in cmts;

cmts.sin_family      = AF_INET;
cmts.sin_port        = htons( 23 );
cmts.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");

sock = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

if ( sock < 0 ) {
    perror("Socket creation error!");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ( connect( sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cmts, sizeof( cmts ) ) < 0 ) {
    perror("Connect process error!");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

write( sock, "testuser\n", 9 );
write( sock, "testenapwd\n", 11 );
write( sock, "terminal length 0\n", 18 );
usleep( 100000 );
read( sock, buf, sizeof( buf ) );
usleep( 100000 );
write( sock, "show cable modem\n", 17 );
usleep( 100000 );

while ( 1 ) {
    nbytes = 0;
    ioctl( sock, FIONREAD, &nbytes );

    if ( !nbytes ) { break; }
    else {
        memset( buf, 0, sizeof( buf ) );
        nbytes = read( sock, buf, sizeof( buf ) -1 );
        printf("%s", buf);
        printf(">>>%d<<<\n", nbytes);  // for debug
    }

    usleep( 300000 );   // delay
}

close( sock );
exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for `read()`/`write()` and learn that at least for sockets those two functions do not necessarily read/write as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity. If you do not know the size of data you could expect to read in advance, go and read the bytes one by one.

Comment: You end your while loop the instant the buffer is empty, not when the other side is done transmitting.  That would be problematic in receiving all the data.

Comment: Try reading a tutorial on sockets. The way you are doing it is very non-standard and makes it very hard to be successful.

Comment: Yes, i know that read() function not necessarily read so much bytes as we give him, and usually we do not know the size of response. If you think you can fix my code, or please show a better solution for this task, so do not hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/)

It's recommended to use the recv and send functions when it comes to networking.

recv returns the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred. The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.